# How to find out why MongoDB is сonsuming so much memory?

Tags: mongodb

We have a MongoDB installation:

```
MongoDB: 3.0.6
MongoDB Engine: mmapv1
Replica: Pri+Sec+Arb
OS: Debian 8.2
Primary node VM mem amount: 10 GB
```

*Unfortunatelly I cannot upgrade this installation in spite of that fact that it has so old software under the hood.*

Usually we have 6 GB of avaible memory on the Primary VM. But after our developers did some updates and inserts on DB a couple days ago, MongoDB on Primary VM started to сonsume 4 gb more and now we have only 2 GB of avaible memory. It works OK, but I would like to find out what happened.

First of all I checked db.serverStatus().mem:

```
{
    "bits" : 64,
    "resident" : 8091,
    "virtual" : 35055,
    "supported" : true,
    "mapped" : 12555,
    "mappedWithJournal" : 25110
}
```

Then I typed db.stats():

```
{
    "db" : "Our DB",
    "collections" : 14,
    "objects" : 1443933,
    "avgObjSize" : 848.8413797593101,
    "dataSize" : 1225670080,
    "storageSize" : 3136176128,
    "numExtents" : 85,
    "indexes" : 25,
    "indexSize" : 162342656,
    "fileSize" : 8519680000,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 128,
        "totalSize" : 2996109312
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I exepected to see the storageSize grown up, but it stayed the same as it had been before developers' actions.

So I still can't understand where these 4GB leaked. Could you give me a hint what can I check else to see the whole picture of the memory consumption?

Comment: When you say memory, you are referencing RAM or disk space?

Comment: Thank you for reply! I'm talking about RAM :)

Comment: Then looking at db stats is "pointless" as Mongo is not an in memory db. The culprits for extreme RAM consumption are usually large queries that aren't supported by indexes or expensive actions such as `$lookup` or `$group` again on large datasets.

Comment: Even if it has mmapv1 engine? I checked mongostat, but didn't see many queries.

Comment: Honestly i haven't met anyone that still uses `mmapv1`, it sounds like your issue's are related to this fact. I do not have former experience using it so I cannot say for sure. regardless unless you are set up to use the in memory storage engine the bulk of your data is saved on disk and disk alone. `mmapv1` saves a "map" on RAM to access disk more efficiently. hence the name m*map*v1.

Comment: I think you are right. I suppose our developers' actions changed structure of data in DB somehow. And that made Mongo consume more RAM. But I have no idea how to check it. :(